# reverse a data frame in R

Tags: r, matrix

```
data<-read.csv(file="blabla.csv",row.names=1)
data<-t(data)
data<-as.data.frame(data)
sapply(data,class) #check the type of data
```

I have a big dataset and I want to transpose it. When I inverse it, it says that all the values are factors. So I can I handle this problem?

I tried to convert it in numerical:  `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(data), nrow=nrow(data))`.

After I transpose the data I want to add a column with the 2 classes as factor. So in the end I need to have a data set with numerical values and the last column with `labels(classes)`.

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
for people to work with. We don't all have "blabla.csv"!

Comment: As a coding question rather than a statistical one, this is really [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
 for this site.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that's happening is because you have a factor in the `data`, so when you transpose it, the levels in that factor get spread to every column in the output.

R can only have one type per vector (column), and when it sees a mixed type it will coerce it all to be the same, in this case it makes all your columns factors.

You need to remove all non-numeric columns from `data` before transposing, then add your factors after.